# Legend for Dumb bell plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to create a simple legend for my dumb bell plot but can't find a way. Is there a way to do so or create the legend manually?

My code is as below:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = industry,
             x = retrenchment_in_year,
             xend = mean_retrenchment)) +  
  geom_dumbbell(size = 1,
                size_x = 2,
                size_xend = 2,
                colour = "black", 
                colour_x = "red", 
                colour_xend = "green")
```

[Dumb bell plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QCjt.png)

I simply would like to indicate what the green and red dot represents in the legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_dumbbell` does not map on the `color` aesthetic. Hence, there is no color legend. One option to add the legend manually is to

1. add two empty `geom_point` layers, one for left points, one for right points
2. map on the `color` aesthetic, which automatically gives a legend
3. set the colors and/or legend labels via `scale_color_manual`

As you provided no example data I made use of the example from `?geom_dumbell`:

```r
df <- data.frame(trt=LETTERS[1:5], l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))

library(ggalt)

ggplot(df, aes(y=trt, x=l, xend=r)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "#5b8124", colour_xend = "#bad744",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(l, NA, color = "x"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(r, NA, color = "xend"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(x = "#5b8124", xend = "#bad744"), labels = c(x = "x", xend = "xend")) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_line(size=0.05)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly! Thank you so much for this and sorry for not providing the example data in the question, still new to all these. Learning as I go!